# ¿Cómo obtener el data-attribute de los radio buttons con JS?

Tags: javascript, html5

Necesito actualizar el precio de un producto, luego de que el usuario selecciona una opción. Pero no me aparece ningún monto de los que tengo en el data-cost de mis radios. He realizado pruebas con varios formatos de funciones pero ninguna me funciona, este es el más reciente que tengo, pero aún no veo la luz. ¿Me ayudan por favor?

Editado -> Perdón. Olvidé mencionar que está es sólo parte de la operación, luego tengo que sumar esto a otros datos. Por lo que necesito que el resultado esté en una variable global.

Este es el html

```
<form method="POST" action="https://tmgmfg.activehosted.com/proc.php" id="_form_29_" class="build-form" validate>
<label><input type="radio" name="field" value="Manual SPT Hammer" data-cost="0"/>Manual SPT Hammer</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="field" value="Automatic SPT Hammer" data-cost="2000">Automatic SPT Hammer</label>
</form>
<div id="options_cost"></div>
```

Este es mi js

```
var hammer = 0;

    function productCost() {
        document.getElementById("_form_29_").onchange = function() {
            hammer = document.querySelector('input[name = field]:checked').getAttribute('data-cost');
        };
    }
productCost();
document.getElementById("options_cost").innerHTML = productCost();
```

Comment: bastaría con poner document.getElementById("options_cost").innerHTML = hammer, dentro de la función productCost()

Comment: @ChristianCarrillo Perdón. Olvidé mencionar que está es sólo parte de la operación, luego tengo que sumar esto a otros datos. Eso afectaría.

Comment: declara hammer fuera de la función y modifica/obtén su valor desde cualquier función

Comment: Osea `var hammer;` fuera de la función?

Answer (score 1):

El codigo te quedaria asi y puedes acceder al valor con el input hidden por su id val_hammer desde cualquier parte de la pagina.

```html
        <form method="POST" action="https://tmgmfg.activehosted.com/proc.php" id="_form_29_" class="build-form" validate>
            <label><input type="radio" name="field" value="Manual SPT Hammer" data-cost="0"/>Manual SPT Hammer</label>
            <label><input type="radio" name="field" value="Automatic SPT Hammer" data-cost="2000">Automatic SPT Hammer</label>
        </form>
           <input type="hidden" id="val_hammer">
        <div id="options_cost"></div>

        <script type="text/javascript"> 
                    var hammer = 0;
                    function productCost() {
                            document.getElementById("_form_29_").onchange = function() {                 
                            hammer = document.querySelector('input[name = field]:checked').getAttribute('data-cost');
                            document.getElementById("options_cost").innerHTML = hammer;
                            document.getElementById("val_hammer").value = hammer;  // hacer global
                        };
                    }               
                    productCost();                    
        </script>
```

Comment: Hola Alex. Buena idea. La implementé de la siguiente forma. Sin embargo, el valor de `var hammer` no cambia. Sale en blanco.

`window.onload = function() {
            document.getElementById("_form_29_").onchange = function() {
            document.getElementById("cost").innerHTML = document.querySelector('input[name = field]:checked').getAttribute('data-cost');
        };
        }
        
        var hammer = document.getElementById("cost").innerHTML;`

Comment: Aquí pongo un fiddle de lo que tengo, pero por alguna razón no logro recuperar el dato en `<p id="cost"></p>`.
https://jsfiddle.net/n4cykb6x/

Comment: Debes poner la asignacion de la variable hammer dentro de la funcion() onchange y quitale var al variable hammer que estas asignando el nuevo valor para que tome la variable global. y deja la  var hammer = 0; como estaba al comienzo.

Answer (score 0):

si quieres una variable global en javascript puedes usar lo siguiente:

```
window.hammer
```

con la propiedad `window` adelante de tu variable se vuelve global y lo puedes utilizar otras partes del código

prueba con esto:

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>

     <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var hammer = 0;

$(function() { 
    console.log("holaaaa");
    function productCost() {
        document.getElementById("_form_29_").onchange = function() {
            hammer = document.querySelector('input[name = field]:checked').getAttribute('data-cost');
            console.log("asadas");
            console.log(hammer);

            $("#options_cost")[0].innerHTML=hammer;
        };
    }

    productCost();
    document.getElementById("options_cost").innerHTML = hammer ;
});
    </script>
</head>
<body>

    <form method="POST" action="https://tmgmfg.activehosted.com/proc.php" id="_form_29_" class="build-form" validate>
<label><input type="radio" name="field" value="Manual SPT Hammer" data-cost="0"/>Manual SPT Hammer</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="field" value="Automatic SPT Hammer" data-cost="2000">Automatic SPT Hammer</label>
</form>
<div id="options_cost"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hola amigo. La variable hammer ya debería ser global, ya que está declarada antes de la función así `var hammer = 1;` Lo que pasa es que al seleccionar un radio button, esta no me actualiza al correspondiente data-cost.

Comment: creo que ya se cual es tu problema lo que pasa es que tienes que poner tu funcion dentro del document.ready que se usa en jquery deberias buscar su equivalente html, creo que tu funcion del evento del radiobutton se esta creando antes de tu html por eso no se ejecuta la funcion, pero si pones tu funcion del evento del radio button en el document ready si deberia funcionar.

Comment: No funcionó. No me tira error en la consola de chrome pero no sale el resultado en el `options_cost`.

Comment: haya falta modificar algo mas chekea la ultima actualizacion

Comment: Nop, nada, ya había probado en .innerHTML poner hammer en lugar de productCost() y no había funcionado.

Comment: ya ahora hasta ya lo probe jeje revisa la ultima actualización

Comment: ten en cuenta que agregue la librería jquery en la parte de arriba

Answer (score 0):

El codigo de JavaScript tiene un pequeño error por eso es que no recibes el valor estas asignando un valor con: document.getElementById("options_cost").innerHTML = productCost();

cuando la funcion es muda y no tiene return. (lo demas veo que esta bien)

prueba con este codigo:

```html
        <form method="POST" action="https://tmgmfg.activehosted.com/proc.php" id="_form_29_" class="build-form" validate>
            <label><input type="radio" name="field" value="Manual SPT Hammer" data-cost="0"/>Manual SPT Hammer</label>
            <label><input type="radio" name="field" value="Automatic SPT Hammer" data-cost="2000">Automatic SPT Hammer</label>
        </form>
        <div id="options_cost"></div>

        <script type="text/javascript"> 
                    var hammer = 0;
                    function productCost() {
                            document.getElementById("_form_29_").onchange = function() {                 
                            hammer = document.querySelector('input[name = field]:checked').getAttribute('data-cost');
                            document.getElementById("options_cost").innerHTML = hammer;
                        };
                    }
                    
                    productCost();
                    
        </script>
```

Comment: Hola @Alexander, gracias por la buena respuesta. Sin embargo, es necesario que el resultado esté en la variable, fuera de function. Para luego continuar con el resto de mi código. Si está dentro del function no puedo hacer lo que sigue.

Comment: Ok se me ocurre que incluyas un input hidden y en la funcion asignes el valor que recibistes, asi tienes acceso desde toda la pagina